# GoSonar : how to generate go test -json > report.json

Tags: go, sonarqube

How to generate `go test -json > report.json`

Golang Version: Go1.10.3

SonarQube Properties: sonar.go.tests.reportPaths = report.json

Offical Sonar Document -> https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Unit+Tests+Results+Import

Makefile

```
.PHONY: test
test:
    @$(foreach package,$(packages), \
        go test -coverprofile $(package)/cover.out -covermode=count $(package);)

.PHONY: cover
cover-xml:
    @$(foreach package,$(packages), \
        gocov convert $(package)/cover.out | gocov-xml > $(package)/coverage.xml;)
```

Comment: I don't understand your question. What are you trying to do, and what problems are you having?

Comment: I think @Rocky wants to put a wiki of sort

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the Makefile, you generate the coverage report using:

`go test -coverprofile $(package)/cover.out $(package)`

To generate the test report you need to add:

`go test -coverprofile $(package)/cover.out -json $(package) > $(package)/test-report.json`

Or if you prefer a single report, you can create an empty file:

`echo -n > test-report.json`

And append all the tests to it:

`go test -coverprofile $(package)/cover.out -json $(package) >> test-report.json`

Note: I removed `-covermode=count` because it's not useful if the report is only used by SonarGo.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, also this analysis in sonarcloud and its source helped a lot for me, https://sonarcloud.io/dashboard?id=io.sonarcloud.examples.go-sqscanner-travis-project . Source: https://github.com/SonarSource/sonarcloud_example_go-sqscanner-travis/blob/master/sonar-project.properties